# How do I create keyboard input in a wpf application?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, keyboard

I want to make a wpf application in c# that displays some text on screen, and where the user is supposed to write a response and press enter to submit the response. I don't want to use a textbox, since there is only one line for the text input in the window, and I don't want the user to have to click to select the textbox. I want the application to be mouse-free.

My question is: How do I make it so that when the user has written their answer, they can submit the response simply by pressing enter?

I have tried the following snippet of code which I found on a microsoft help website:

```
private void OnKeyDownHandler(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Return)
        {

            doSomething();
        }
    }
```

I suppose I have to add some code elsewhere, but I'm not sure where or what I need to add.

Comment: " I don't want to use a textbox, since there is only one line for the text input in the window"... so what are you using?

Comment: Maybe a textblock or a label. But on second thought, I might use a textbox, as long as accidentally pressing the mouse doesn't deselect the textbox.

Comment: But, do you require the user to type in something before pressing enter key or not?

Comment: Yes, the user types a response and then presses enter, and then some new text appears and so on.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to make sure your window process every Enter key press without care what control is focused you can use PreviewKeyDown event:

```
private void Window_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
    {
        //Process user input
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Of course if you are doing mvvm you can create a behavior to encapsulate the event handler:

```
 public class WindowBehavior : Behavior<Window>
    {
        protected override void OnAttached()
        {
            AssociatedObject.PreviewKeyDown += AssociatedObject_PreviewKeyDown;
        }

    private void AssociatedObject_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Enter from Window");
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        AssociatedObject.PreviewKeyDown -= AssociatedObject_PreviewKeyDown;
    }
```

I suggest you to read [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/464926/To-bubble-or-tunnel-basic-WPF-events) about bubble, tunneling and direct events basic for WPF events.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a button that you're using for submit, you can easily set it as the default by using the `IsDefault=true` (wrote a tip about doing this and the cancel for the escape [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/665886/Button-Tip-IsDefault-IsCancel-and-other-usability).)

Other than that, you'll have to have somewhere to write it (yet you don't want a textbox? you can select it by default, or tab into it if you don't have the focus there), and you can handle the keydown to "catch" the `Enter` otherwise.

Comment: "and you can handle the keydown to "catch" the Enter otherwise."

What do you mean by this?

Comment: You can handle the keyboard event on the textbox, and show the next question when enter was pressed.